# How to determine cause of Host thresholds exceeded: [Threads] in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, async-await, azure-functions

I'm running an Azure Function under the Consumption Plan. The Host Health Monitor is shutting it down every week or two due to hitting the Threads thresholds. I've read most of what I can find about this (e.g., starting with https://aka.ms/functions-thresholds) and understand what the health monitor is doing. Most of the articles I've read discuss the Connections threshold, not Threads. What I'm unable to figure out is how to troubleshoot this deeper and determine which part of my code is causing the threading issue. I'm not using any explicit TPL code. I'm doing a lot of very basic/standard async await operations against a REST API using a static HttpClient and standard crud operations against CosmosDB using a static DocumentClient. The only two Task-related methods I'm calling are async and await. I'm not using any retry patterns in this function. Application Insights doesn't give me much in the way of telling me what calls are creating threads, what threads still open or abandoned, etc.

Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot things deeper? I've opened a support ticket with Microsoft and am waiting on their help as well.

Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are a couple of things to consider like

- The number of functions in your function app
- The number of async operations (2 in your case)
- The number of parallel executions at a moment

Functions in the Consumption Plan scale based on the number of events (uses heuristics) that are triggered ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#runtime-scaling)) up to 200 instances without a limit on concurrent executions in a single instance.

So, even if you have async/await code, multiple long-running concurrent executions could cause problems I believe. Also, what triggers you use and at what rate they are triggered would influence the scale out.

To workaround the problem you could

- Split the function app into multiple function apps if possible
- Use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview) which should allow you to scale your long running operations, if any

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestions.  Still working with MSFT to troubleshoot.  There are 4 functions in the app that call into services, but none are long-running at all (a few seconds at best). There are quite a few more than 2 async operations, but MSFT reviewed some code and said it conforms to async best practices.  I guess I don't understand the autoscaling well enough. I'd think if thresholds were being reached the app would autoscale.  The function app probably only sees maybe a few thousand hits a day right now.  Still looking... I'll post updates if/as I learn more from support.

Comment: @TomHundley Curious to know how did you end up resolving this problem. I am having similar problem.